# ElasticSearch routing field

Tags: elasticsearch

Are there any guidelines for selecting a field to be used for routing in ElasticSearch? Previously we've had success using the `user_id` for an index of about ~750K documents (we have about 10K users).

For a second index, I didn't use the `user_id` field, and instead used a different ID that was much larger (750K). Performance seems subpar, but its hard to pin down if the routing field is the cause (it is required), as there are 30 million documents stored.

(I'll admit I'm thinking the query analyzer works in a similar fashion to a traditional SQL based one, and this may not be the case.)